# draggable connections with raphael library

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, raphael

I have two draggable rectangles and I want to do draggable connections for them. How can I do that? here is my code;
http://jsfiddle.net/XcsN/ztkzn/

```
function move_arrows(num)
{
    for(x=0;x<arrowCounter;x++)
    {
        arrows[x].yol1.remove();
        arrows[x].yol2.remove();
        arrows[x].yol3.remove();
        arrows[x].yol4.remove();
        arrows[x].yol5.remove();
        arrows[x].yol6.remove();
        arrows[x] = new ARROW(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html). Is that what you're trying to accomplish? Side note: you can use an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Array_Literals) instead of `new Array()` for clearer, more concise code.

Comment: Thanks for answer.I saw this demo but I did not understand how to work.

Comment: The problem has been solved by me.

Comment: Well done! You can either delete your own question, or write up (and accept when the site lets you) your own answer, below.

Comment: 404 error for the jsfiddle link ;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to draw a line with Raphael, you must use "path" function. 
But it is not appropriate for dragging. 
Firstly, you have to calculate new coordinates, then you can remove and redraw it, so you can have draggable connections.